# Using LinkedList for storing elevator requests?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, queue, priority-queue

I am designing an elevator system. To store the requests from passengers, my first approach was to use a FIFO queue. But that won't work in the following scenario:

Initially, queue = { }
Elevator requested on 5th floor | queue = { 5 }
Elevator requested on 3rd floor | qqueue = { 5, 3 }

Now, the elevator will stop on floor 3 on its way to floor 5. If I use a FIFO queue, it will remove the first element (5) instead of 3 from the request list when it reaches the 3rd floor. So a queue isn't the right data structure for this.

I was thinking of storing the requests in a Linked List. Will it work? Currently, I can't think of a scenario where it won't work. Also, a lot of people recommend using 2 or 3 priority queues for this, but again, I don't understand why that will work. Can someone please shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Just saying "use a linked list" doesn't tell us much about what you're proposing. How are you planning to arrange the list so that the program knows when to stop?

Comment: Your question seems to indicate an implied requirement of "fairness" amongst different button presses. Can you elaborate on what those are?